# split a row value according to a specific column

Tags: sql-server, update, computed-column, row, string-splitting

I have total value in table A and need to get row value in table B until reached value in table A.

**Table A**

| ID | Available |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 99 |
| 2 | 0 |

**Table B**

| ID | Rack | RequiredQty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 60 |
| 1 | B | 102 |
| 1 | C | 8 |
| 2 | A | 10 |

**Expected Results**

| ID | Rack | RequiredQty | FulfilledQty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 60 | 60 |
| 1 | B | 102 | 39 |
| 1 | C | 8 | 0 |
| 2 | A | 10 | 0 |

Comment: You can find in this link , some ways to do it: https://sqlperformance.com/2021/12/t-sql-queries/supply-demand-challenge

Comment: is it possible to use cte to get the fullfilledqty breakdown?

Comment: In what order do you want to fulfill the quantities for a given `ID`?...by `Rack` alphabetically?

Comment: Cumulative SUM in CTE by table 2, join table 1, compare, calculate additional column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE to produce a running total and subtract that from the required quantity:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT ID, Rack, Required
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Rack ASC) AS Rn
  FROM TableB
), CTE2 AS (
  SELECT b.ID
    , b.Rn
    , b.Rack
    , b.Required
    , CASE
        WHEN b.Required > a.Available THEN a.Available
        ELSE a.Available - (a.Available - b.Required) 
      END AS Fulfilled
    , CASE
        WHEN b.Required > a.Available THEN 0
        ELSE a.Available - (a.Available - (a.Available - b.Required))
      END AS Available
  FROM CTE b
  INNER JOIN TableA a ON a.ID = b.ID
  WHERE b.Rn = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT b.ID
    , b.Rn
    , b.Rack
    , b.Required
    , CASE
        WHEN b.Required > a.Available THEN a.Available
        ELSE a.Available - (a.Available - b.Required) 
      END AS Fulfilled
    , CASE
        WHEN b.Required > a.Available THEN 0
        ELSE a.Available - (a.Available - (a.Available - b.Required))
      END AS Available
  FROM CTE b
  INNER JOIN CTE2 a ON a.ID = b.ID AND a.Rn = b.Rn-1
  WHERE b.Rn > 1
)

SELECT ID
  , Required AS RequiredQty
  , Fulfilled AS FulfilledQty
FROM CTE2
ORDER BY ID, Rack
```

You can see a working example in this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6babb8eb2cb722b0e22bb1107a4d5d23), which produces the below output:

| ID | Rack | RequiredQty | FulfilledQty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 60 | 60 |
| 1 | B | 102 | 39 |
| 1 | C | 8 | 0 |
| 2 | A | 10 | 0 |